# Why in docker-compose after recreate conteiner i get "Docker cannot link to a non running container"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two conteiners:
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ......
    network_mode: bridge

  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    ........
    network_mode: bridge
    external_links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    name: postgres_data
```

After docker-compose up, when i recreate only one container - "db", all works, but i can not connect to conteiner "web", i get error: "Failure
Cannot link to a non running container: /postgres AS /web/postgres".
In conteiner "web" i call db as host=postgres.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `external_links:` setting is obsolete and you don't need it.  You can just remove it with no adverse consequences.

`network_mode: bridge` and `container_name:` are also unnecessary, though they shouldn't specifically cause problems; still, I'd delete them.  What you show can be reduced to

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ......

  web:
    build: .
    ........
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data: # empty
```

Since Compose creates a network named `default` for you and attaches containers to it, your application container can still reach the database container using the hostname `db`.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.

Comment: if i remove external_links, i get error, when i up my another app: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known. It`s app i run in another docker-compose file

Comment: You've named your database container `db`, not `postgres`, and the application database configuration needs to match that.

Comment: my container database have name admin_site